# nginx subdomain and domain rewrite w proxy pass

Tags: django, proxy, nginx, url-rewriting

I need these two types of rewrites:

`subdomain.domain.com => domain.com/website/subdomain`

`otherdomain.com => domain.com/userdomain/otherdomain.com`

My problem is that I want the user to see `subdomain.domain.com`, and `otherdomain.com`, not the redirected version. My current rewrite in nginx works, but the user's URL shows the rewrite, and I want this to be transparent to the user, any ideas?:

```
upstream domain_server { server localhost:8000 fail_timeout=0; }     

server {
        listen  80;
        root  /var/www/domain.com;

        server_name domain.com ~^(?<subdomain>.*)\.domain\.com$ ~^(?<otherdomain>.*)$;
        if ( $subdomain ) {
                rewrite ^ http://domain.com/website/$subdomain break;
        }
        if ( $otherdomain ) {
                rewrite ^ http://domain.com/userdomain/$otherdomain break;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_redirect off;
                proxy_buffering off;
                proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
                proxy_set_header X-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                if (!-f $request_filename) {
                        proxy_pass http://domain_server;
                        break;
                }
        }

}
```

Comment: found something interesting here: http://blog.martinfjordvald.com/2011/02/nginx-primer-2-from-apache-to-nginx/. It says "Another thing about Nginx rewrites is that by default they are internal rewrites, which means that they won’t change the URI the browser sees. They will only do that if you specify the “redirect” or “permanent” rewrite flag or if you rewrite to an absolute URL including the http:// part.". Trying to use this to come up with a solution...

Answer (score 29, accepted):

With nginx you don't need rewrites at all.

```
upstream domain_server { server localhost:8000 fail_timeout=0; }

proxy_set_header Host domain.com;
proxy_set_header X-forwarded-for $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

server {
    listen  80 default_server;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://domain_server/userdomain/$http_host;
    }
}

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name domain.com;

    root  /var/www/domain.com;

    location / {
        try_files $uri @backend;
    }

    location @backend {
        proxy_pass http://domain_server;
    }
}

server {
    listen  80;
    server_name ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.domain\.com$;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://domain_server/website/$subdomain$request_uri;
    }
}
```

- http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass
- http://wiki.nginx.org/IfIsEvil
- http://wiki.nginx.org/Pitfalls
- http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/converting_rewrite_rules.html

Comment: Thanks for the great response, however, /var/www/domain.com/userdomain/$host doesn't exist, but the URL domain.com/userdomain/$host does. The idea was to transparently proxy the user to that URL when they use their own domain that is pointed to the server

Comment: using proxy_pass still redirects the browser URL, I'm still trying out different configurations with this...

Comment: So, probably, it's on the application side now. Your application must know how to generate appropriate links.

Comment: I just spawned a new instance and used apache to replicate this domain configuration and have no problems with the same application. So it's definitely the nginx conf for sure. Still working on it :)

Comment: Could you provide dubug log, or, at least, equivalent apache configuration? I expect that you missed something, like slash at end of URIs.

Comment: I posted an apache solution as an answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10557590/multiple-domain-hosting-with-one-django-project/10558314

Comment: Ok. In your apache config you rewrite to
`domain.com/userdomain/otherdomain.com/` but not to `domain.com/userdomain/otherdomain.com` like you mentioned in question. So, just add slashes to proxy_pass: `proxy_pass http://domain_server/userdomain/$http_host/;`
and `proxy_pass http://domain_server/website/$subdomain/;`.

Comment: that fixed it! I edited the post to add the slashes. Thanks a million!

Comment: another addition may be to add `$request_uri` so it becomes `http://domain_server/website/$subdomain$request_uri/`

Comment: why am I getting `invalid host in upstream: http://domain_server` could you tweak your code a bit to a noob friendly one? Thanks.

Comment: It's already noobiest one. It may be used just by copy-n-paste into `http { }` section. You're probably doing something wrong. And I can't help until I don't know what you're doing.

Comment: @Vbart please [check this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724338/map-subdomain-requests-to-a-controller).